# Managing module versions in Terraform

Tags: terraform

As the number of our Terraform repositories grow it's becoming an issue making sure that all references to a module use the latest tagged version.

How are people managing their Terraform module dependencies?

Ideally, something that would give a warning when a later tag of the module is available when running a plan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a solution but to make it more noticable that there is a later module version available, we have written a custom pre-commit hook which checks to see that if a new version is available as displays a warning.

Other option is to use something like Terragrunt which managing the module version can be done in code.

Answer (score 1):

`Latest` is evil (same applied to docker image tag) :-)

Please source the terraform module with tag

Sample:

```
module "vpc" {
  source = "git::https://example.com/vpc.git?ref=v1.2.0"
}
```

With that, infrastructure or application team can continuously move on with new features without impact to other teams or projects which reference this module.

Comment: That's what we are doing, how do you manage searching through all your code and updating to v1.3.0?